# Getting "1" as value of IDENT_CURRENT('TableName') for replicated article table in subscriber database in sql server

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am getting "1" as value of IDENT_CURRENT('TableName') for replicated article table in subscriber database in sql server. Actually it should be same as table in publisher database.

Any solution and setting to back it correct figure?

Answer (score 1):

This could well be down to design in so far as you are not directly inserting the identity when replicating. The actual mechanism in use may be at a lower level and should you actually want to insert directly into the subscriber table, you may find it works as it should (I am not recommending you try this however!)

You could try checking/updating the value an re-running your query

[DBCC CHECKIDENT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)

Comment: Actually i want proper identity value for the disaster so i make it live for production when main publication production database not available. But the insertion will fail because of identity violation.